# Where can I publish on an undergraduate course that I helped develop and teach?

Tags: undergraduate-education, education-research, undergraduate-research, publishing

I co-developed and co-taught an interdisciplinary course with several colleagues from several departments for junior/senior college students. This was a very interesting experience, and I am wondering if I may just report/publish how the mathematical part was organized and taught.

> **Question:** What journal or journals might accept publications of this nature?

Comment: What disciplines were involved?

Comment: You can find some "practitioner journals" listed [**here**](http://mathedjournals.wikispaces.com/Practitioner+Journals). Though the corresponding link there is broken, I suggest checking NCTM's [**Mathematics Teacher**](http://www.nctm.org/publications/mathematics-teacher/) (working link) to see if it fits the bill. (**Also:** You may wish to specify more carefully the nature of your work with this course - specifically, the mathematics/math education components...)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that one of the disciplines involved was mathematics and you have some novel insights or ideas about how to create such a course, [PRIMUS](http://www.tandfonline.com/loi/upri20) is a good generalist option, especially if you can "aim" the article at other undergraduate faculty who might be interested in creating such a course but aren't sure where to start.